# How to detect changed height edittext using wrap content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to detect edittext height change after text change. edittext height is wrap_content. if edittext changed line number, i will set recyclerview smoothScrolltoposition to bottom.

My code.

```
var lineNumber: Int = 0;
this.edtMessage.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

       if (lineNumber != edtMessage.lineCount && messages.size > 0)
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messages.size - 1);
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        lineNumber = edtMessage.lineCount;
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe edit_text.getMeasuredHeight() can help?

Comment: i want to watch, after line count changed. i will change scroll position